# Windows or Linux for Monero

Tags: mining-software, daemon, windows, linux

### What are the pros and cons of each OS for running a full node and GPU/CPU mining? Also developing for Monero?

I want to be able to make programs for windows, linux, and macos that involve Monero as I want to be more involved in the community.

I have a R7 250 and a intel xeon 4core/8thread 3 ghz

Should I stay on Windows, or go on Linux, because my life is currently revolving around cryptocurrency and developing.

Whats the pros and cons of each system for developing, mining, and running a full node.
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As someone who runs both Windows and Linux, I'd say that there is no bad choice but there certainly are better ones for specific use cases.

- Casual use: Windows - no need to dual boot or learn a new OS. Mining, running a full node work fine.
- Competitive mining: Linux for superior performance
- Storing funds: Linux for superior security. (Still requires sane best practices like not running a web browser on a machine with >$xx,xxx worth of monero on it)
- Storing lots of funds: Neither. Use a paper wallet generated on an offline machine.
- Development: Hands down Linux, unless you are a strong C# dev and know your way around the windows development environment.

Comment: You have made up my mind along with pebx. I'm going to switch from Windows to Linux (I already have experience and all I really do is browse the internet, develop, and use/mine cryptocurrencies) I did a quick test and my CPU hashes faster and GPU doesn't really change. Do you have any suggestion for what flavor I should choose?

Comment: @UsernameVF Ubuntu and Linux Mint are generally pretty good for beginners.

Answer (score 6):

That's a pretty broad question...

If you just want to run a full node, I would recommend some (small) VPS on Linux, since even 20GB of storage space will be enough and you will be able to run it with any amount of RAM will be OK for that purpose.

If you want to mine and involve your GPU, I would prefer Windows, since GPU drivers are usually better than on Unix systems. However, don't expect to be able to work on that system, if you really want to mine, since with a good config it will pretty much consume 100% of your CPU and GPU.

If you want to develop for Monero, it's up to you which editor or testing environment you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Why use one software when you can utilise Virtual machines on existing software that you are currently running.

I personally use oracle VM VirtualBox (no affiliation just my software that I use).

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Its not to hard to get to grips with, just watch a few youtube videos and you will pick it up quickly if you are computer technically minded.

Comment: I know how to use it, but it doesn't give me full power that I could have.

Comment: Just offering an alternative option buddy!... it could also help for people who view this question also!

Comment: I understand, but I don't think mining on a virtual machine would be the best at times. But thank you for the option. I will prob run a VM on linux if I ever need to use visual studio or something. <3

Comment: In a VM you always have some overhead, so from mining perspective it's the worst option.

Your answer also isn't really reflecting the question, since you *can* run multiple systems on one machine, but that was not the question.